# How to set up ID3 algorith in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, tree, machine-learning, scikit-learn

There is a [DecisionTreeClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier) for varios types of trees (ID3,CART,C4.5) but I don't understand what parameters should I pass to emulate conventional [ID3 algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3_algorithm) behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says

> scikit-learn uses an optimised version of the CART algorithm.

so you probably cannot emulate an ID3 as found in the textbooks.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that it's the only differences between sklearn implementation and ID3 algo, but from what i know you have to change criterion from "gini" to "entropy" for ID3

```
DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy")
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to provide categorical attributes as Input? For example, X = [[True, False, True], [False,False, True], [True, True, False]], Y = [Class1, Class2, Class3]. In the example they have only shown for numerical data. Thanks

Comment: @AnkurBhatia old question, but just in case anyone was still wondering, scikit only supports numerical data for now. See their docs for more details: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#

Comment: To convert categorical data to numerical values, you can use scikit's `preprocessing.OrdinalEncoder` work with your data that way.

Comment: Also, it is still using CART under the hood. Just using entropy instead of gini for the criterion.

Answer (score 0):

Use Id3Estimator using following:

```
from id3 import Id3Estimator
estimator = Id3Estimator()
```

and then fit your data

```
estimator.fit(X, y)
```